# How to send a SOAP object with FEIGN client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, feign

I'm trying to send a SOAP message via a FEIGN client. The problem is that when I send the java object, what is actually being sent is a request with an xml format, instead of a SOAP format.

The client is configured as follows:

```
@FeignClient(name = "calculatorServer", url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx")
public interface AEMWebServiceFeignClient{

    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML, produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    AddResponse calculate(@RequestBody Add addRequest);

}
```

Looking at the log I see that I am really sending this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <intA>2</intA>
    <intB>0</intB>
</Add>
```

When I really should be sending the following message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>2</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>0</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must define a custom Feign codec to use SOAP, as described in [here](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/tree/master/soap).

To integrate it with FeignClient, you should define a custom configuration class for it, [reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults).

```java
@FeignClient(
  name = "calculatorServer", 
  url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx"
  configuration = MySoapClientConfiguration.class)
public interface AEMWebServiceFeignClient{

    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML, produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    AddResponse calculate(@RequestBody Add addRequest);

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MySoapClientConfiguration {

    private static final JAXBContextFactory jaxbFactory = new JAXBContextFactory.Builder()
       .withMarshallerJAXBEncoding("UTF-8")
       .withMarshallerSchemaLocation("http://apihost http://apihost/schema.xsd")
       .build();

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new SOAPEncoder(jaxbFactory);
    }
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new SOAPDecoder(jaxbFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved!! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to integrate this with wsdl files, also can we define a context path for JAXBContextFactory ?

Comment: @Álvaro was it really solved? SOAPEncoder does not populate SOAP related headers as per source code.

Answer (score 2):

It's works, but i had added:

1. Create package-info.java into package addRequest/AddResponse

```
    @XmlSchema(
            namespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
            elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
            xmlns = {
                    @XmlNs(prefix = "xsd", namespaceURI = "http://tempuri.org/")
            }
    )
    package your.package.add;
    
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

2. Also, you need to add an interceptor to set content-type and soapAction:

```
    import feign.RequestInterceptor;
    import feign.RequestTemplate;
    
    public class FeignRequestSoapInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    
        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
            requestTemplate.header("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            requestTemplate.header("soapAction", "http://tempuri.org/Add");
        }
    }
```

3. In MySoapClientConfiguration, add the FeignRequestSoapInterceptor:

```
@Configuration
public class MySoapClientConfiguration {

    private static final JAXBContextFactory jaxbFactory = new JAXBContextFactory.Builder()
            .withMarshallerJAXBEncoding("UTF-8")
            .build();

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new SOAPEncoder(jaxbFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new SOAPDecoder(jaxbFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public FeignRequestSoapInterceptor feignRequestSoapInterceptor() {
        return new FeignRequestSoapInterceptor();
    }
}
```

4. FeignClient:

```
    @FeignClient(
      name = "calculatorServer", 
      url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx"
      configuration = MySoapClientConfiguration.class)
    public interface AEMWebServiceFeignClient{
    
        @PostMapping("/Add")
        AddResponse calculate(@RequestBody Add addRequest);
    
    }
```