# Consume SOAP with Spring Boot and Feign client

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I am struggling to properly make a SOAP request with open feign client and get the response. For testing purposes i took this public SOAP service http://www.learnwebservices.com/ and this is WSDL -> http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL

I generated classes from this WSDL that looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SayHello", propOrder = {
    "helloRequest"
})
public class SayHello {

    @XmlElement(name = "HelloRequest", required = true)
    protected HelloRequest helloRequest;

//getters and setters
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "helloRequest", propOrder = {
    "name"
})
public class HelloRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
//getters and setters
}
```

And i tried to follow this example:

[How to send a SOAP object with FEIGN client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621218/how-to-send-a-soap-object-with-feign-client)

basically i created this feign config:

```
private static final JAXBContextFactory jaxbContextFactory = new JAXBContextFactory.Builder()
        .withMarshallerJAXBEncoding("UTF-8")
        .withMarshallerSchemaLocation("http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL")
        .build();

@Bean
public Decoder feignDecoder() {
    return new SOAPDecoder(jaxbContextFactory);
}

@Bean
public Encoder feignEncoder() {
    return new SOAPEncoder(jaxbContextFactory);
}
```

And then here i try to invoke end point like this:

```
@FeignClient(name = "feign-example",
        url = "http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/hello",
        configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface WogSeb20FeignClient {
    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    HelloResponse get(@RequestBody HelloRequest addRequest);
}
```

First when i tried to do the call i got error that says HelloRequest is missing XmlRootElement, so i added that annotation to the class (even i am not sure what to put as root element, i just added @XmlRootElement on top of the class. Afterwards when i create a request i get this error:

```
Error during parsing response data. Status: 500, Cause: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Message part helloRequest was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Obviously i am doing something wrong, can someone give me some guidance since i was not able to find too much material regarding this topic.

Comment: Hey mate, were you able to solve the issue?